# Devise causing Heroku errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

**UPDATE**The logout issue has been fixed by making a single line change in `routes.rb`, to `config.sign_out_via = :delete`. I understand that this allows a user to sign out by using the HTTP delete method. What I REALLY don't understand is how the `create new post` feature is working after this change. If someone could explain this I would be incredibly grateful.

**UPDATE:** I should have mentioned that my Production db is up to date, heroku run rake db:migrate was the first solution I encountered while googling, but has not fixed my issue.

Also, I am using AWS S3 to store images, which was previously working fine, until I added my Devise functionality

The app in question is hosted on my GitHub [here](https://github.com/adam-wanninger/imgfall)

My image sharing app is working perfectly in my development environment, using sqlite. In production (on Heroku) I am using postgres. I imagine that this problem is related to using Devise with Postgres.

The problem arises when I try to create a new post at `http://imgfall.herokuapp.com/posts/new` or logout once signed in `http://imgfall.herokuapp.com/users/sign_out`.

The sign out link just shows the standard Rails error page saying `The page you were looking for doesn't exist.` This appears to be a routing problem, but I don't know the solution. My routes for production seem to be the same as for development, so there shouldn't be an issues (right?)

I've checked the heroku logs, which shows the following error related to creating a new post:

```
Started GET "/posts/new" for 174.102.98.169 at 2015-08-15 16:19:47 +0000
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms
Processing by PostsController#new as HTML

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: user_id):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:31:in `new'


Processing by PostsController#new as HTML

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: user_id):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:31:in `new'


Started GET "/posts/new" for 174.102.98.169 at 2015-08-15 16:19:47 +0000
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
```

and the following error related to logging out:

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 174.102.98.169 at 2015-08-15 16:21:19 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out"):
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

When I run `Heroku run rake routes` I get:

```
Running `rake routes` attached to terminal... up, run.9186
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)               devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)              devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                     registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                            registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                    registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                       registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                            registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                            registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                            registrations#destroy
           post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                         POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
        new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
       edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
            post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
                    root GET    /                                           posts#index
```

Here are my routes for the development environment:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                    devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)               devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)              devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                   devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                     registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                            registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                    registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                       registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                            registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                            registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                            registrations#destroy
           post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                         POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
        new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
       edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
            post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                         DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                         POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
                new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                         DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
                    root GET    /                                           posts#index
```

Comment: The first issue `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: user_id):` is most likely due to your heroku database schema not being brought up to date. Fix it with `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: The second is that you don't actually have a `DELETE /users/sign_out` route only GET. This could be caused by your routes or by the Devise configuration.

Comment: I should have mentioned that my Production db is up to date, `heroku run rake db:migrate` was the first solution I encountered while googling, but has not fixed my issue.

Comment: could this be an issue with amazon S3 storage that I am using for images?

Comment: and I am honestly not sure how to create a DELETE route for `/users/sign_out`

Comment: Rake routes shows --
destroy_user_session     GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy 
no route for DELETE

Comment: Good catch @praveen. I corrected this to the default in `devise.rb`, but when I run `heroky run rake routes` I still see `destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                   devise/sessions#destroy` Is this correct? If not, what needs to be updated?

Comment: The sign out error still occurs, and the logs still show `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out"):`. I realize that I need to adjust my routes to accept an HTTP method of DELETE for this action, but I don't know where to do do that...

Comment: @praaveen the second issue is now solved. I fixed the `devise.rb` file and set `config.sign_out_via = :delete`. I can now log out successfully in production. The first issue in my OP still remains, however.